# Proof $\exists\alpha$ s.t. $P(X>\alpha)>0$ if $P(X>0)>0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

For probability triple $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$ prove that for a random variable $X$, if $\mu(X>0)>0$, there must be $\alpha>0$ s.t. $\mu(X>\alpha)>0$.

So if $X$ is a random variable with that property, it means that $\exists $ event $ A \in \mathcal{F}$ and interval $B=(0, \infty)$ s.t.
$$
A:\{\omega \in \mathbb{R}: X^{-1}(B)= A \}, \mu(A)=m>0
$$
Since $A$ is an interval, we can set its upper and lower bounds as $\beta_1, \beta_2$. Since $A \in \mathcal {F}$, we can certainly find number $\alpha^{-1}$ such that there exist two disjoint intervals $A_1 \cup A_2=A$ with the same measure:
$$
A=A_1 \cup A_2, A_1 = [\beta_1, \alpha^{-1}], A_2 = [\alpha^{-1}, \beta_2], \mu(A_1)=\mu(A_2)=\frac{m}{2}
$$
Obvisouly $\alpha^{-1} \in A$, and, since $A$ is a preimage of $B,  \alpha^{-1} = X^{-1}(\{\alpha\})$, and $\alpha \in B$. Therefore
$$
A_2 = \{\omega:X^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)\}
$$
and $\mu(X>\alpha) = \mu(A_2)=\frac{m}{2}>0$.

I think this is correct, but the hint for the problem is to use the continuity of probabilities, which I didn't.

Comment: Take $\alpha = 0$? Is there meant to be some condition on $\alpha$?

Comment: @KennyWong $\alpha>0$, I added the condition

Comment: How did you get that $A$ is an interval? All you did was assume that $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and that it is the preimage of an interval by $X$.

Comment: Why is $A$ interval? What if $X(\omega)=\sin(\omega)$?

Comment: Hint: What happens if $\mu(X > \frac{1}{n}) = 0$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: @d.k.o. if $B$ as above, its preimage must be an interval?

Comment: If $B$ is an interval, then its preimage must be a Borel set

Comment: @AndrewShedlock so this probability triple and measurability of $X$ don't together imply  $A$ is an interva?

Comment: @DominikKutek so on what sets would Lebesgue measure be non-zero then? $\frac{1}{n}$ rationals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the expanding sequence of sets $A_n = \{ X > \frac{1}{k}\}$. Notice $ \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{ X > \frac{1}{k}\} = \{X > 0\}$. Since $A_n$ is an expanding sequence of sets, then by the Monotone Convergence Theorem for sets $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n) = \mu\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\Big) = \mu(\{X > 0\}) > 0$$
We then get that $$0 < \mu\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\Big)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k)$$
Since the series $\sum \mu(A_k) > 0$ and each term is nonnegative, then at least one term must be positive, for otherwise $\sum \mu(A_k) = 0$.

Comment: Notice that from $\lim_n\mu(A_n)>0$, it follows that there is $n_0$ such that $\mu(A_n)>0$ for all $n\geq n_0$. So the remaining of your argument, though correct, it is unnecessary.

Comment: For sure, just a classic

Comment: @AndrewShedlock thanks, is the last step ($\sum_n \mu(A_n) = 0 $ iff $ \forall \mu(A_n)=0$) an 'obvious' fact or requires an additional proof?

Comment: I think it is obvious, but best to include for clarity

Answer (score 2):

The set $E_n=\{X>\frac1n\}$ increases to $E=\{X>0\}$. By monotone convergence
$0<\mu(E)=\lim_n\mu(E_n)=\sup_n\mu(E_n)$

From this, it follows that $\mu(E_n)>0$ for all sufficiently large $n$.